# Does special relativity change how we should think of other people's consciousness alongside ours

Tags: time

Does special relativity change how we should think of other people's consciousness alongside ours.

I've been reading a lot on here and am not sure what to think.

It's pretty crazy really I didn't know all this info last week.

If our now moments don't line up what does this mean for your experience relative to me.

Are you and me every experiencing together

Comment: Wasn't that already posted yesterday?

Comment: The conclusion was that special relativity was not saying anything about consciousness, whatever that may be.

Comment: Someone else posted this. I wasn't sure what the answer was

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Special Relativity - Discussions I've seen online](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/97753/special-relativity-discussions-ive-seen-online)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it changes how we should think about our experience of time, but not of consciousness.

To get from one place to another, we have always needed to know how non-conserved quantities vary, and then we find special significance in what does not vary - conserved quanties, and the conservation laws that govern them. We can talk about those as what is 'invariant under transformation', and use the rules that govern that to understand how things look from different places, given there is no absolute frame of reference. This website gives a great explanation and tools for getting better intuitions about this in relativistic mechanics:[Inside Einstein's head](https://www.lucify.com/inside-einsteins-head/). View in desktop mode or a pc for full options.

This picture challenges our deep intuition that everything is moving against a neutral static background of space and time. [The Principle of Locality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_locality) shows us that spatial seperation is more accurately thought about as a specific continuous-symmetry transformation relation, that is space and time fundamentally are the product of the conservation laws that apply between objects. This becomes of crucial significance in considering [ER = EPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ER_%3D_EPR), the widely supported mainstream conjecture that entanglement between objects is a result of a non-local connection that we can call an Einstein-Rosen Bridge, or a wormhole.

Are we experiencing everything together? Yes, every gravitational mass in the universe is acting on you right now, within constraints of lightspeed for propagation of changes (eg Cosmological Event Horizons). Yet, each position of observation can be treated as it's own restframe, as it's own point at which signals arrive constrained by the symmetry-operations of space and time. We can think of space and time not as necessary precursors for events, as philosophers like Kant believed, but as emergent from the relationships between objects, and what will be involved for signals and other perturbations or interactions to operate between them. Should that impact how we understand consciousness? Depends what you start with as a view. I would describe it as strong support for the metaphor [Indra's Net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indra%27s_net), which is essentially the idea that reality is a peer-to-peer network.

Comment: +1 "Reality is a peer-to-peer network". Fascinating metaphor.

Comment: What will you do with "reality is a peer-to-peer network" if SR is superseded by another theory tomorrow?

Comment: @Frank: Update my picture, like any good scientist. However, wishing for spacetime to be different than this is very much like wishing the luminiferous ether was real after all - that horse is long gone, & new theories have to encompass current results, plus new ones, not discard them or try to turn the clock back on what we know.

Comment: Sure - superseded, updated ... and compatible with the rest of the observations.

Comment: Also, if you really want to push it, the particles you are made of talk to each other at the speed of light only, which is finite, so between the right and the left side of your brain, things happen at different times. So we never really hold a complete idea in our mind: some parts of our brains have part of the idea at t1, others at t2, ...

Answer (score 1):

Special relativity only enters into the question in the form of something called the *clock synchronization problem*. Roughly speaking, this has to do with the fact that the speed of causality in our universe is the speed of light, and if you try to synchronize your clock with another which is some distance away, it can't be done because the hand position of the distant clock is seen by you as being in your present when it is actually in the past of the distant clock, by the amount of time it took the light from that clock to travel the distance to your eyes.

It takes a beam of light one millionth of a second to travel a thousand feet, and for this reason special relativity has no impact on interpersonal relationships since no human can sense the passage of one millionth of a second.

Comment: Isn't relativity more complicated than just light signals

Comment: of course it is. what is your point exactly?

Comment: Well, if I approach you does a version of you that exists in your future exist for me, due to hypersurfaces of simultaneity or is this an overcomplication. Why do these notions of now not mean we should think different about all of our friends

Comment: you are free to think about this in any way you wish.

Answer (score -1):

No one is conscious at the same time as us, you think about your friend having experience when you look at them, special relativity forbids this happens at the same time as they have experience

But now isn't real, there's no such thing as now. So when are your friends experiencing ? Depends on your reference frame... What is a reference frame? A tool for making models.

Are you conscious with me? Who knows

This is why I reject relativity

Comment: Do you have GPS on your phone or in your car? If you truly "reject relativity", you have to give up on those.